Meaning of expressions within curly brackets in JBoss EAP 8.0 ldap-realm attribute-mappings
I am trying to use an ldap-realm in JBoss EAP 8.0.  In the attribute-mappings section, there are expressions I don't understand.  For example, this Elytron Security document has:
  <ldap-realm name="ldap-realm" dir-context="ldap-connection" direct-verification="true">
    <identity-mapping rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="ou=users,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org">
      <attribute-mapping>
        <attribute from="uid" to="Roles" filter="(uniqueMember={1})" filter-base-dn="ou=groups,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org"/>
      </attribute-mapping>
    </identity-mapping>
  </ldap-realm>

and this one has:
<attribute filter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member={0}))" from="CN" to="role"/>

What is the meaning of {0} and {1} in these contexts?

These are placeholders, they represent user-supplied inputs.
